# In a word containing $k$ A's, how many permutations place at least $n$ A's consecutively?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose a word is $l$ letters long, and it contains $k$ A's. (The specific letter is irrelevant) Is there a general formula to count how many permutations contain at least $n$ consecutive A's? (Assume $n \leq k$)

Comment: If the word contains only A's, then *all* "permutations" contain exactly $l$ consecutive A's. I guess that *all* means $1$ in this special case. The number will depend on the number of other letters and their multiplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little easier to count permutations which do *not* contain $n$ consecutive $A's$. For now, assume that all the letters not equal to $A$ are the same, say they are all $B$.

There are $l-k$ $B$'s. These divide the string into $l-k+1$ blocks of $A$'s. In each of these blocks there are between zero and $n-1$ $A$'s. Therefore, the number of permutations is equal to the number of integer solutions to the following equations and inequalities:
$$
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{l-k+1}=k,\\
0\le x_i<n\quad\text{ for }1\le i \le l-k+1
$$
Using the generating function method, this is equal to the coefficient of $t^k$ in $(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{n-1})^{l-k+1}=(1-t^n)^{l-k+1}(1-t)^{-l+k-1}$, which can be found to be
$$
{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/n\rfloor} (-1)^i\binom{l-k+1}{i}\binom{l-ni}{l-k}}
$$
Recall, this is the number of permutations without any $n$ $A$'s in a row. The complementary count is given by subtracting from $\binom{l}k$, resulting in
$$
\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor k/n\rfloor} (-1)^{i+1}\binom{l-k+1}{i}\binom{l-ni}{l-k}}
$$
If the letters besides $A$ are not all the same, say there are $r$ other varities of letter and $m_i$ letters in the $i^{th}$ variety, then you have to multiply the above quantity by the number of ways to permute the letters, which is the multinomial coefficient
$$
\binom{l-k}{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_r}=\frac{(l-k)!}{m_1!\times m_2!\times \dots\times m_r!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote that number as A(l, k, n). It is easy to see, that $A(l, k, n) \neq 0$, iff $n \leq k \leq n$. Now, let's assume that.

If a permutation contains $n$ consecutive letters 'A', then it is one of two cases:

1) Its prefix of length $l - 1$ contains $n$ consecutive letters 'A', and the last letter is not A. There are $(l - k)A(l - 1, k, n)$ such permutations.

2) Its prefix of length $l - 1$ contains $n$ consecutive letters 'A', and the last letter is not A. There are $A(l - 1, k - 1, n)$ such permutations.

3) Its suffix of length $n$ consists only of 'A'-s. There are $(l - n)!$ such permutations.

However, if $n < k$ the cases 2 and 3 are not disjoint. A permutation is in their intersection iff either its $(n + 1)$-suffix consists only of 'A'-s ($(l - n - 1)!$ such permutations exist) or its prefix of length $l - n - 1$ contains $n$ consecutive letters 'A', its suffix of length $n$ consists only of 'A'-s and its $l - n$-th letter is not 'A' ($A(l - n - 1, k - n, n)(l - k)$ such permutations exist).

Thus the number of such permutations is defined by the recurrence relation $$\scriptstyle{A(l, k, n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } n > k \text{ or } k > l \\ (l - k)A(l - 1, k, n) + A(l-1, k-1, n) + (l-n)! &\quad \text{if } n = k \leq l \\ (l - k)A(l - 1, k, n) + A(l-1, k-1, n) + (l-n)! - (l - n - 1)! - A(l - n - 1, k - n, n)(l - k) & \quad \text{if } n < k \leq l \end{cases}}$$